# Redux Toolkit Causes Redux Restart When Reducer Code Changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux Toolkit for state management in my React application, and I've encountered a strange issue. Whenever I make changes to the reducer code, my Redux store seems to restart, causing unexpected behavior and data loss.

**Here's a snippet of my store configuration:**

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import RootReducer from './reducers/RootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middleware = [thunk];
const devtools = (x) => x;

export const Store = configureStore({
  reducer: RootReducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), ...middleware],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  enhancers: [devtools],
});
```

**And here's a portion of my reducer code:**

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    user_list: {},
    total_user_list: 0,
    active_user: {},
}

const ChatRoomSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'chat_room',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateActiveUser: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.active_user = payload || {}
        },
        updateUserList: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.active_user = payload[0] || {};
            state.user_list = payload;
            state.total_user_list = payload?.pagination?.total_value
        },
    }
})
```

Whenever I make changes to the ChatRoomSlice reducer, such as adding or modifying actions, it appears that Redux restarts, causing my application to lose its state. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Redux Toolkit? Is there a specific way to update the reducer without triggering a full Redux store restart?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour, as changed files need to be reevaluated. Changing your slice files means the createStore function needs to rerun, causing all slices to be recreated and set to their initialState.